# C# Predicate Builder with "NOT IN" functionality

Tags: c#, predicatebuilder

With PredicateBuilder how do I get functionality similar to the SQL IN or NOT IN query?

For example I have a list of IDs and I want to select all of the People whose IDs either Match or do not match the IDs.

The people match functionality is fairly straightforward (although there may be a better way to do it)

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Person>()
foreach (int i in personIDs)
{
  int temp = i;
  predicate = predicate.Or(e=>e.PersonID == temp);
}
return persons.Where(predicate);
```

So how do I get the opposite?  I want all persons whose IDs are not in the personIDs list.

Comment: As a workaround I was able to get the list of PersonIDs prefiltered so I can just use the code above.  It's not ideal, but it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Ask [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> NOT (P OR Q) = (NOT P) AND (NOT Q)

To have your code generate the equivalent of a NOT IN condition, rewrite as

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Person>()
```

and

```
predicate = predicate.And(e=>e.PersonID != temp);
```

Comment: That is what I tried the first time, however I am getting an empty result set from SQL.  When I inspect the SQL from Profiler I get something to the effect of
SELECT
CAST(NULL as varchar(1)) as [C1], 
.
.
.
FROM (SELECT 1 as X) AS [SingleRowTable1]
WHERE 1=0

Answer (score 3):

Do you use Entity Framework?

Then you can build the query without PredicateBuilder:

```
var personIds = new List<int>() { 8,9,10 };
var query = persons.Where(it => !personIds.Contains(it.PersonId));
```

From this LINQ statement a SQL NOT IN query is created.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Person>()
foreach (int i in personIDs)
{
    int temp = i;
    predicate = predicate.And(e => e.PersonID != temp);
}
return persons.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the api....

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Person>()
foreach (int i in personIDs)
{
    int temp = i;
    predicate = predicate.And(e=>e.PersonID != temp);
}
return persons.Where(predicate);
```